# Lose state in React Js

Tags: reactjs

I have an application with 2 inputs; name and password. Also, I have a save button that should change the state, using the values from the inputs, in the parent component.

But now, if I insert just one value in one input, I lose the state in the parent component. For example, if I type just name, and click save button, in the parent component I lose the password value, but I don't know why.

How to avoid this using my code?

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Test = ({ user, setUser }) => {
  const [u, setU] = React.useState("");
  const [p, setP] = React.useState("");

  function name(e) {
    const a = e.target.value;
    setU(a);
  }

  function password(e) {
    const a = e.target.value;
    setP(a);
  }

  function save() {
    console.log(u);
    setUser({ ...user, name: u, password: p });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={name} />
      <input onChange={password} />
      <button onClick={save}>save</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    password: ""
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    setUser({ name: "john", password: "Doe" });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{user.name}</p>
      <p>{user.password}</p>

      <Test user={user} setUser={setUser} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

code link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ytowzg

Comment: @Ramesh, why? I used in my child component  `setUser({ ...user, name: u, password: p });`. Does this update the parent state?

Comment: Yes, it should. What you have is a logical error, see my answer.

Comment: it is working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a better proposition,instead of using a separate state variable for name ,password and percentage use a single state variable object

**Test.js**

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { InputNumber } from "antd";
    import "antd/dist/antd.css";

    const Test = ({ user, setUser }) => {
      const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: "",
        password: "",
        percentage: ""
      });

      function onChange(e, name) {
        setState({
          ...state,
          ...(name === undefined
            ? { [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
            : { [name]: e })
        });
        console.log(state);
      }

  function save() {
    setUser({
      ...user,
      ...(state.name !== "" && { name: state.name }),
      ...(state.password !== "" && { password: state.password }),
      ...(state.percentage !== "" && { percentage: state.percentage })
    });
  }


      return (
        <div>
          <input name='name' onChange={onChange} />
          <input name='password' onChange={onChange} />
          <InputNumber
            defaultValue={100}
            min={0}
            max={100}
            formatter={value => `${value}%`}
            parser={value => value.replace("%", "")}
            onChange={e => onChange(e, "percentage")}
          />
          <button onClick={save}>save</button>
        </div>
      );
    };

export default Test;
```

Updated CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-fire-ngu95)

Comment: i like the code, but what if i i am using besides simples inputs, ant design `Input Number`, and there i can't get input name like `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`. How to combine this situation?

Comment: i reproduced the issue. How in this case to set the state properly?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ytowzg

Comment: i'll take a look at it , hold on

Comment: i have updated the code , this should work for both `Input Number` simple `input` and antd `Input`

Comment: If to change :  const Test = ({ user, setUser }) => {
      const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: "john",
        password: "Doe",
        percentage: "100"
      });
 to :   const Test = ({ user, setUser }) => {
      const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: "",
        password: "",
        percentage: ""
      });. Appear a, issue when i try to save just one value , because others disappear in the parent component after clicking. How to save these values in case if i will  set just one?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand the question , only the value that you enter gets changed in the parent component is that not what you wanted? , Check the Codesandbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210330/discussion-between-asking-and-abdullah-abid).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is great. But could you help me, please, in case if to use and Range Picker from here https://codesandbox.io/s/choose-time-ant-design-demo-hltui, and Select from here https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-already-selected-ant-design-demo-pjfre. How in this case to manage the state? Because here i can't set name for shure, and i can't acces [e.target.name]. Which could be the solution?

Comment: if the `onChange` returns an `event` , it will have store the value in one it's property , you need to just log the event, find the property which has the value and access it

Answer (score 2):

This should fix your issue:

```
  function save() {
    console.log(u);
    if(u === '') {
      setUser({ ...user, password: p });
    } else if (p === '') {
      setUser({ ...user, name: u });
    } else {
      setUser({ ...user, name: u, password: p });
    }
  }
```

So, now the state is conditionally updated based on the values of the input fields. The issue with your code is that you're always overwriting the state regardless of the input values.